Pytorch, Can't find the inplace operation that's preventing my network from calculating gradient
I'm trying to implement Proximal Policy Optimisation with multiple Actor heads: there are multiple actions the agent can perform, so I need one head to chose which action(s) to perform, and then several others to determine the parameters of the chosen action
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
from torch.distributions.categorical import Categorical
from gymnasium.spaces import Discrete
from icecream import ic

# Since I'm using dictionaries to store outputs based on which
# action head they related to, I need functions to convert
# dicts of tensors to tensors

def logprobdict_2_tensor(logprob_dict):
    for k, v in logprob_dict.items():
        if len(v.shape)==2 and v.shape[0]==1:
            logprob_dict[k] = v[0]
    return torch.concatenate(list(logprob_dict.values()))

def tensorise_dict(act_dict, device):
    return OrderedDict({k: t if isinstance(t, torch.Tensor) else torch.tensor(t, device=device) for k, t in act_dict.items()})


# Policy and value model
class ActorCriticNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, obs_space_size, action_space_sizes, device:str="cpu",):
        super().__init__() # manadatory
        self.policy_layers: dict[str, nn.Sequential] = {}

        torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

        self.action_choices = [
            ['gp_new'],
            ['gp_continue'],
            ['use_mem', 'gp_new'], # note, actions will be performed in list order, if more than one is specified
            ['use_mem', 'gp_continue'], 
            ['store_mem'],
            ['publish'],
            ['read']
        ]
        self.action_choice_space = Discrete(len(self.action_choices))
        self.device = device

        # shared layers for all heads, including critic
        self.shared_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(obs_space_size, 64).double(),
            nn.ReLU().double(),
            nn.Linear(64, 64).double(),
            nn.ReLU().double())
        
        # action choice head
        self.policy_layers['choice'] = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(64, 64).double(),
            nn.ReLU().double(),
            nn.Linear(64, self.action_choice_space.n).double())
        
        # dict of heads for specific action paramers
        for name, size in action_space_sizes.items():
            self.policy_layers[name] = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(64, 64).double(),
                nn.ReLU().double(),
                nn.Linear(64, size).double())

        # critic
        self.value_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(64, 64).double(),
            nn.ReLU().double(),
            nn.Linear(64, 1).double())

    def value(self, obs):
        z = self.shared_layers(obs)
        value = self.value_layers(z)
        return value
        
    def choose(self, obs):
        return self.policy(obs, 'choice')
        
    def policy(self, obs, choice):
        z = self.shared_layers(obs)
        action_logits = self.policy_layers[choice](z)
        return action_logits

    def forward(self, obs): # mandatory

        torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

        z = self.shared_layers(obs)
        action_logits = {}
        action_logits['choice'] = self.policy_layers['choice'](z)
        choice_distribution = Categorical(logits=action_logits['choice'])
        choice = choice_distribution.sample()
        choice_log_prob = choice_distribution.log_prob(choice).item()
        for action in self.action_choices[choice.item()]:
            action_logits[action] = self.policy_layers[action](z)
        value = self.value_layers(z)
        return choice, choice_log_prob, action_logits, value
  

class PPOTrainer():
    def __init__(self,
                actor_critic: ActorCriticNetwork,
                ppo_clip_val=0.2,
                target_kl_div=0.01,
                max_policy_train_iters=80,
                value_train_iters=80,
                policy_lr=3e-4,
                value_lr=1e-2):
        self.actor_critic = actor_critic
        self.ppo_clip_val = ppo_clip_val
        self.target_kl_div = target_kl_div
        self.max_policy_train_iters = max_policy_train_iters
        self.value_train_iters = value_train_iters
        self.policy_params = {}
        self.policy_optims = {}

        value_params = list(self.actor_critic.shared_layers.parameters()) + \
            list(self.actor_critic.value_layers.parameters())
        self.value_optim = optim.Adam(value_params, lr=value_lr)

        for k, layers in self.actor_critic.policy_layers.items():
            self.policy_params[k] = list(
                self.actor_critic.shared_layers.parameters()
            ) + list(layers.parameters())
            self.policy_optims[k] = optim.Adam(self.policy_params[k], lr=policy_lr)

    @property
    def device(self):
        self.actor_critic.device

    def train_policy(self, obs, acts, old_log_probs, gaes, which, actions, mask=None):
        for _ in range(self.max_policy_train_iters):
            # If a network is used at every step (like 'choice'), no mask needed
            obs, gaes = (obs[mask], gaes[mask]) if mask is not None else (obs, gaes)

            self.policy_optims[which].zero_grad()

            # Here, we calculate the new log probs, which is different
            # (simpler) for 'choice' than everything else
            if which == 'choice':
                new_logits = self.actor_critic.choose(obs)
                new_distro = Categorical(logits=new_logits) 
                new_log_probs = new_distro.log_prob(acts)
            else:
                new_logprobs_list = []
                for ob1, ac1 in zip(obs, acts):
                    new_logits = self.actor_critic.policy(ob1, which)
                    new_distros = actions[which].logits_2_distros(new_logits)
                    act_part_log_probs = tensorise_dict(OrderedDict({
                        k: d.log_prob(ac1[k]) for k, d in new_distros.items()
                    }), device=self.device)
                    new_logprobs_list.append(logprobdict_2_tensor(act_part_log_probs))
                new_log_probs = torch.stack(
                    new_logprobs_list, 
                    dim=0
                ).to(self.device, dtype=torch.float64)

            policy_ratio = torch.exp(new_log_probs - old_log_probs)
            clipped_ratio = policy_ratio.clamp(
                1 - self.ppo_clip_val, 1 + self.ppo_clip_val)
            
            if len(clipped_ratio.shape) > 1:
                gaes = gaes.expand(1, gaes.shape[0]).permute((1,0))
            clipped_loss = clipped_ratio * gaes
            full_loss = policy_ratio * gaes
            policy_loss = -torch.min(full_loss, clipped_loss).mean()

            policy_loss.backward()
            self.policy_optims[which].step()

            # If the new probability distro diverges too far from the old,
            # stop training and get new training data
            kl_div = (old_log_probs - new_log_probs).mean()
            if kl_div >= self.target_kl_div:
                break

    def train_value(self, obs, returns):
        for _ in range(self.value_train_iters):
            self.value_optim.zero_grad()

            values = self.actor_critic.value(obs)
            value_loss = (returns - values) ** 2
            value_loss = value_loss.mean()

            value_loss.backward()
            self.value_optim.step()


def discount_rewards(rewards, gamma=0.99):
    """
    Return discounted rewards based on the given rewards and gamma param.
    """
    new_rewards = [float(rewards[len(rewards)-1])]
    for i in reversed(range(len(rewards)-1)):
        new_rewards.append(float(rewards[i]) + gamma * new_rewards[-1])
    return np.array(new_rewards[::-1])

def calculate_gaes(rewards, values, gamma=0.99, decay=0.97):
    """
    Return the General Advantage Estimates from the given rewards and values.
    Paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02438.pdf
    """
    next_values = np.concatenate([values[1:], [0]])
    deltas = [rew + gamma * next_val - val for rew, val, next_val in zip(rewards, values, next_values)]

    gaes = [deltas[-1]]
    for i in reversed(range(len(deltas)-1)):
        gaes.append(deltas[i] + decay * gamma * gaes[-1])

    return np.array(gaes[::-1])

Here is the error trace:
/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:266: UserWarning: Error detected in AddmmBackward0. Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/philoso_py.py", line 192, in <module>
    model.run(100, 25)
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/philoso_py.py", line 54, in run
    asyncio.run(self.day(steps_per_day))
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 672, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 639, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1985, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/agent.py", line 91, in day_step
    choice, choice_log_prob, action_logits, val = self.nn(obs)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/ppo.py", line 157, in forward
    z = self.shared_layers(obs)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 217, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 116, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
 (Triggered internally at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/python_anomaly_mode.cpp:118.)
  Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/philoso_py.py", line 192, in <module>
    model.run(100, 25)
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/philoso_py.py", line 55, in run
    self.night()
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/philoso_py.py", line 78, in night
    agent.night()
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/agent.py", line 276, in night
    self.trainer.train_policy(
  File "/Users/xan/CodeToJoy/philoso-py/ppo.py", line 256, in train_policy
    policy_loss.backward()
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 522, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/Users/xan/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 266, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.DoubleTensor [64, 64]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 81; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

I'm new to working with pytorch and haven't encountered this problem before.
I've set up anomaly mode, according to which the problem seems to be with one of my linear layers in the shared layers. However, this makes it all the more baffling as I can't think of anywhere in my code that directly alters this. I tried cloning obs at the start of the forward call, based on a suggestion elsewhere, but that didn't help. Can anyone see what I missed? I'm using pytorch 2.2.2.
